# Why are there two verbs in one clause

Tags: grammar

> But these days, of course, there are fewer and fewer donors left who I
> remember, and so in practice, I haven’t been choosing that much. As I
> say, the work gets a lot harder when you don’t have that deeper link
> with the donor, and though I’ll miss being a carer, it **feels** just
> about right to be finishing at last **come** the end of the year.

at the last sentence,has two verbs: feel,come. is this grammatical correct?
this paragraph come from a novel whose author is The Nobel Literature winner,so I think this is not likely to be typo

Comment: "Come the end of the year" is a separate subordinate clause functioning as an adjunct. Nothing unusual here.

Comment: @BillJ at least one dictionary (Oxford Languages) describes 'come' used this way as a 'preposition'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey your answer is the best

Answer (score 2):

*Come the end of the year* is a way of saying 'when the end of the year comes', so *come* isn't a main verb in the sentence.

Compare the folk song 'I'm seventeen come Sunday'.